# Getting basic authentication box appear when trying SSO (Websphere/keytabs)

Tags: websphere, spnego, keytab

I am trying to auto login via SSO on an app that is hosted within WebSphere.  When i navigate to the SSO URL, it is asking me for a username and password - when i put the credentials in, this works fine.  I believe that the issue is within the keytab but everything i have looked at online, seems to indicate that's fine.

### The problem

I have an 2x app server that is hosted within Azure, domain joined to **domain1.org**

These two servers are joined to a load balancer, within Azure but using dns **dev-domain1.org**

**Note:** *I have tested reverting all dns from **dev-domain1.org** to the AD domain **domain1.org** and SSO works.*

### SPN User

Created within AD: User: `DOMAIN1.ORG\USERNAME` with SPN `HTTP/env.domain1.org`

Created the keytab with the following command:

```
ktpass.exe -princ HTTP/env.domain1.org@DOMAIN1.ORG -mapuser DOMAIN1.ORG\USERNAME -pass [PASSWORD] -crypto all -kvno 0 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out "F:\PATHTOKEYTAB\.keytab "
```

### Updated .conf file

```
~~ [libdefaults] ~~
    default_realm = AD_DOMAIN
    default_keytab_name = FILE:F:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\keytab
    default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-md5
    default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-md5
    forwardable  = true
    renewable  = true
    noaddresses = true
    clockskew  = 300
[realms]
    AD_DOMAIN = {
        kdc = DC01.ad_domain:88
        default_domain = ad_domain
    }
[domain_realm]
    .ad_domain = AD_DOMAIN
    .dns_domain = AD_DOMAIN
```

Does anyone know how i should be setting up the keytab or even WebSphere itself if i want to use another domain for the URL that is different to the AD/internal domain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify - it all works if your server is in domain1.org, but id doesnt if it is in dev-domain.org? To work across different domains you need to configure trust relationship between the domains  - see here for some more details - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=issmwua-single-sign-http-requests-using-spnego-web-authentication

Comment: @Gas the dev-domain.org isn't an actual domain, it's just a DNS zone.  Essentially, all the servers etc are domain joined on our domain and we want to use DNS name to browse/sso etc.

Comment: Did you try to debug? Enable the following `com.ibm.security.jgss.debug` , `com.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug` and set the trace string `com.ibm.ws.security.spnego.*=all`. The other option to consider could be to use OIDC instead of SPNEGO.

Comment: Also, typically this problem appears when your browser doesnt correctly recognize `dev-domain.org` domain as internal/trusted to perform integrated authentication, so double check that.

Answer (score 0):

you stated.. if I want to use another domain for the URL that is different from the AD/internal domain?

Are you asking DNS domain or an AD domain?
For example, my URL has DNS with server1.ibm.com but the AD domain is domain1.com?

If so first you need to make sure in the AD domain DNS is able to lookup the URL server1.ibm.com

Next, you need to map ibm.com with AD domain domain1.com under krb5.ini file check this URL https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-zos/9.0.5?topic=server-creating-kerberos-configuration-file and example  -dns austin.ibm.com|raleigh.ibm.com

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I am saying that yes. The app servers etc are domain joined on domain1.org and we have a DNS domain which we are wanting to use to nav to the webserver which is dev-domain1.com.

So i can nslookup the dev-domain1.com from my laptop - so i'm assuming thats all fine?  I also have a pointer on my 'onprem' AD domain dns zone that points to the same host?

I haven't got both -dns mapped though.  Only the one!  So are we saying i need both `dns domain1.org|dev-domain1.com` added in here?

Comment: yes if your DNS domain in the URL is dev-domain1.com and the AD domain realm name domain1.org..  Map the DNS with Domain realm name using dns domain1.org|dev-domain1.com

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the issue and the login box is still appearing.

I will amend the OP with the updated .conf file